# Why my questions was closed and why I can't VTR it?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Can someone explain me why [my question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/127791/109878) was closed? It:

- Seems valid. Asks about RPi's core hardware (RJ45 port and chip controlling it).
- Touches important topic (Why RPi is so extremely slow in relatively fast networks?).
- Has a pretty much perfect answer (That low hardware is most likely responsible).

Also, why I cannot vote reopen it? Why there is no *Reopen* button visible for me? Is this due to my low rep in this site?

Answer (score 2):

Only the people who voted to close your question can answer why they **voted** to close it. In this case, five (5) people with a large aggregate of *reputation points* were among those voters. You may disagree with their *opinions* (and that's all they are really), but I feel you should accept the fact that *good intentions* do not guarantee an outcome you favor. And so I cannot explain why your question was judged as off-topic, but you may wish to consider the following:

- There have been 33,973 questions asked on RPi SE. This figure includes [8,851 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered). Many of these questions **should** have been closed. Closing questions is absolutely essential to the viability of S.E. - it's a [*signal-to-noise* issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio).
- There are many, many articles/blog posts/FAQs/etc on the Internet [REF1](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=measure+raspberry+pi+ethernet+speed&t=ffab&atb=v278-1&ia=web), [REF2](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=raspberry+pi+maximum+ethernet+speed&t=ffab&atb=v278-1&ia=web) that address your question - or something similar. [Here's one that you may wish to peruse](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=208512).
- It's fairly well-known that RPi have traditionally suffered from Ethernet performance shortcomings due to their decision to use the USB 2.0 pipeline to move the data. ["The Foundation" copped to this years ago.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/faqs/#networking-gigaperf). One might consider their pronouncements re Gigabit Ethernet as false advertising. Please also understand that Raspberry Pi **is not** an open system, and wrt the hardware and firmware, there is only limited visibility.

Again, this is no answer to your question, but hopefully some food for thought.

Comment: You've explained (in details -- thank you) the first half of my question. Though I must admit that I know, understand most of, if not all of your arguments and that I totally agree with them / with you. But asking why my questions _was closed_ was more like side question. The most important question here (and you seems to be not addressing it in your answer) is a technical question on why _I cannot vote to reopen it_? I have dozens, if not hundreds of closed questions in my entire SE history, but I think I recall that I was able to see and click "Reopen" button under every one. Here -- not.

Comment: Is this because of my very low reputation? Do I need to have a certain level of rep to gain some kind of "vote to reopen" privilege? BTW: Your [last link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/faqs/#networking-gigaperf) actually answers my questions precisely.

Comment: @trejder: I can't answer that question as I don't know the specific rules for *re-opening* a question. One of the administrators could probably explain that. I can say that from my *personal experience* on SE, I've never been able to get one of my questions re-opened - even after an extensive re-write.